# Use Immer with Recoil

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs, immer.js

I'm hoping to get the performace benefits of Immer and the state management of Recoil but don't know how to synchronize the state from [useImmer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-immer) with that of [useRecoilState](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/useRecoilState/).

Answer (score 2):

The core of immer is the [produce](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/produce/) function, which applies changes performantly.

To use it with recoil simply use `produce` *inside* `setState`, instead of `useImmer`.

```js
import { RecoilState, useRecoilState } from 'recoil'
import { produce, Draft } from 'immer'

type DraftFunction<T> = (draft: Draft<T>) => void

export const useRecoilImmerState = <T>(atom: RecoilState<T>) => {
  const [state, setState] = useRecoilState(atom)
  return [
  state,
  useCallback((valOrUpdater: T | DraftFunction<T>) => 
  setState(
    typeof valOrUpdater === 'function'
      ? produce(valOrUpdater as DraftFunction<T>)
      : valOrUpdater as T
    ), [setRecoilState])
  ] as const
}
```

This approach is very similar to how [useImmer](https://github.com/immerjs/use-immer/blob/master/src/index.ts) works.